# How to stop centering a div as soon as it hits the edge of the screen

Tags: css, css-float, media-queries, positioning

i want to create a flexible layout, but I have one div which has to have a fixed width of 1000px.  the best solution i had was to center the div while there was enough space available but when the screen became 1000px or smaller in width, the div would `float:left`.  I'm aware that I could do this using media queries, but im already using those for different dimensions right now and wanted to explore other options.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: You're already using media-queries, but you don't want to use *more* media-queries, because..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much left with media queries or using some JavaScript. Media queries are really the best approach for this due to performance and their declarative nature.

Comment: yeah, i figured as much. i was just curious if there were other options

Answer (score 0):

You should make it responsive and that would be with media queries or in your css, you should set the size in percentage for it to adapt with the user interface size. Simply make it responsive